# position css popUp

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to apply the position `top`and `bottom` of `header` to the `NewUser` div, but this is not working. What am I doing wrong? How do I add the `!important;` to the CSS? Something like `$("header")!important}`

```
<div id="divNewUser" class="CreateUserModal" runat="server">
    <p>
        Use the form below to create a new user account.
    </p>
</div>

<script>
    function showDialog() {
        var modal_dialog = $("#divNewUser");
        modal_dialog.css({     
            position: { 
                my: "top", 
                at: "bottom", 
                of: $("header")
            }     
        });
    }
</script>
```

```
    <div id="accountname1" style="position:relative;float:right">
        <div id="divLogin" style="position:relative; margin-right:1px; margin-top:1%; float:right">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <anonymoustemplate>
                    <img src="/images/btn_login.png" alt="Login" />
                    <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="A3" runat="server" title="Sign in with your account details">Login</a> |
                    <a id="A4" href="~/Account/Register.aspx" runat="server" title="Sign up for your 30 days free trial">Free Trial</a>
                </anonymoustemplate>
                <loggedintemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:Label id="UserLogonID" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
                    <br />
                    [<asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/login.aspx" />]
                    <br />
                </loggedintemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>

            <p style="text-align:right">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFreeTrialDays" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </p>

        </div>

        <div id="mobile-btn">
            <img src="/images/menu_btn.png" alt="Menu Button" />
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about using the `addClass()` function to add a class with the styles you needed that are defined in your css stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vhwp5qmq/1/)

Update your jQuery code :

```
$("#divNewUser").position({
                 my: "top",
                 at: "bottom",
                 of: "header"

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function showDialog() {
    var modal_dialog = $("#divNewUser");
    modal_dialog.addClass("test");
    });
}
```

```
.test{
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    }
```

like that you can set position